# Chrome - if jquery-simple-combobox is inside a modal collapses when mouse dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn to work with `jquery.scombobox` but I'm stuck when adding the scombobox to a modal

```
<div id="modalA" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <select id="combo-021">
                        <option value="1">item 1</option>
                        <option value="2">item 2</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="4">item 3</option>
                        <option value="5">item 3</option>
                        <option value="6">item 3</option>
                        <option value="7">item 3</option>
                        <option value="8">item 3</option>
                        <option value="9">item 3</option>
                        <option value="10">item 3</option>
                        <option value="11">item 3</option>
                        <option value="12">item 3</option>
                        <option value="13">item 3</option>
                        <option value="14">item 3</option>
                        <option value="15">item 3</option>
                        <option value="16">item 3</option>
                        <option value="17">item 3</option>
                        <option value="18">item 3</option>
                        <option value="19">item 3</option>
                        <option value="20">item 3</option>
                        <option value="21">item 3</option>
                        <option value="22">item 3</option>
                        <option value="23">item 3</option>
                        <option value="24">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option value="3">item 3</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



$('#combo-021').scombobox({
showDropDown: true // this is what is set by default
});
```

For multiple items it adds a scrollbar in the right. I can scroll trough the items by using the mouse scroll wheel but when trying to click on the scrollbar and dragging it, the dropdown collapses. Did anyone encounter the same problem? Why is this happening?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D652n/144/)

Comment: Can you provide a working example please? Would be way easier to help you

Comment: Can you upload the HTML and JS somewhere so that we can see the issue in action?

Comment: Added JSFiddle to the question

Comment: Can you provide a link for the "jquery scombobox" plugin?

Comment: Are you displaying this in Jquery dialog ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
tabindex="-1"
```

When you delete this attribute, it works correctly.

Here is more info about `tabindex`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

(Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3fr0aeo/)

Comment: Yes, But how does it impact the slider event by Mouse drag ?

Comment: That's the answer, thanks! But why this happened, why is affected by tabindex?